# Cannot get a document that exist in Firestore from the first time

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an app with two activities, `LoginActivity` and `MainActivity`. In the first activity, I authenticate the user and put its `uid` in an `Intent`. In the second activity, I get the `uid`, using the following line of code:

```
String uid = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid"); //Works fine
```

When I first sign-up and try to use the following lines of code in `onCreate`:

```
DocumentReference uidRef = rootRef.collection("users").document(uid);
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
        if (document.exists()) {
            User user = document.toObject(User.class);
            if (user != null) {
                String name = user.getName();
                textView.setText(name);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "document doesn't exist!");
        }
    }
});
```

I get in the logcat: `document doesn't exist!` even if I see at that location (`users -> uid`), the document exists. If I close the app and start it again, everything works fine. How to get the name displayed from the first time?

Edit: And this is how I add the user to the database:

```
String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
String userName = firebaseUser.getDisplayName();
User user = new User(userName);

DocumentReference ref = db.collection("users").document(uid);
ref.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        DocumentSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
        if (!snapshot.exists()) {
            ref.set(user);
        }
    }
});
```

Edit:

```
public class User {
    private String name;

    public User() {}

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
         return name;
    }
}
```

Database:

[image]

Comment: Also add the code where you are creating the user and sending the details in firestore database. Also check the users uid is same in auth module and firestore database @loanaP.

Comment: @Raj I have added the code that I use in the `LoginActivity` to add the user to the database. Why to see if the `uid is same in auth module`? I'm getting `"document doesn't exist!"`. Btw, thanks for your comment, hope you can help me.

Comment: Also add the db structure and the model class i.e User.java @loanaP.

Comment: @Raj Code / db added.

Comment: Do a log of this uid DocumentReference uidRef = rootRef.collection("users").document(uid); -  the one you are passing here and check if it matches with the uid present in database @loana P.

Comment: @Raj Yes, it matches since the second time I'm starting the app, everything works fine. Do you have any idea why it doesn't work? Thanks!